# Long sections in jquery-scrollify

Tags: jquery, jquery-scrollify

Using [jquery-scrollify](https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify), if there are sections longer than the window, a user skips to the next section before they get a chance to scroll the complete section. I understand the author has added new methods and options to deal with this problem, but I cannot find any documentation or explanations anywhere that would illuminate me.

Any explanations or answers would be great.

Comment: Share your code first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behaviour of Scrollify is to scroll normally over long sections so that the user always sees all the content within every section.
You can see this behaviour on the demo site.

Comment: Thanks Luke. I checked again and it was an error on my part. But thanks for replying as it clarified default behaviour so I could get to the issue. (Which was a css property being over-ridden